# Very Tricky CSS Scrolling Question

Tags: css, scroll, overflow

I am not sure how to achieve a certain effect in CSS.
I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="container" name="container">
    <div id="scroll" name="scroll"></div>
 </div>
```

The scroller loads with one image inside the scroller which has
a  width: 715px;

[ [1]          ]

When the user clicks on that image, a second image is dynamically
appended to the first:

[ [1] [2]     ]

And, when the second is clicked, the same thing happens (and so on):

[ [1] [2] [3] ]

Now, here is where I need some help. When the final visible image in
the series is clicked on, the preceding images should
scroll to the left to make room for the new one, putting the first out
of view and placing the new image at the end as such:

[ [2] [3] [4] ] 
<-------------->

This goes on indefinitely - each time the final image is clicked the
preceding ones should scroll to the left, placing the new image at the
right-most view within the DIV.

[ [3] [4] [5] ] 
<-------------->

I have played with the below CSS (what you see is the state of my
most recent attempt). What I have been able to achieve is:

1) The images build consecutively and then overflow (to the right) 
when the fourth image exceeds the 715px mark. Not what I want.

2) The below CSS "Does" do what I want (sort of) - it starts on the left of 
the DIV and then works to the 715px mark and starts to push the images (backwards)
to the left and out of view - always leaving the most recent image
to the far right of the DIV and in view. THE PROBLEM with this is 
that the order is FLIPPED (I think, due to RTL). I have tried to 
trick it with text-align:left but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Any Ideas? Suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

```
#container
{
    width: 715px;
    height: 228px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    / * text-align:left; */
}

#scroll
{
    height: 228px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: rtl;
    /* text-align:left; */

}
```

Comment: may be on http://doctype.com/ you will get better help

Comment: thanks. I created an account and posted my question there too. But, if anybody here knows the answer... please help!

Comment: How are you adding the dynamic behavior? With pseudo-classes or js?

Comment: The dynamic behavior is done with JS if, by dynamic behavior you mean the click event and new image being appended to the end of the sequence. This is done and works extremely well. The rest I should be able to do with CSS but can't figure it out.

Comment: if the content is being added with JS, why not handle the scrolling through JS as well? It's a simple matter of absolute positioning and some math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a [demo page](http://elv1s.ru/x/s/stackoverflow.com/questions/1475320/). It works well on Firefox, Safari, Opera, and IE 8.

It's actually JS solution. Magic goes here:

```
document.getElementById('container').scrollLeft = last_img.offsetLeft;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, I finally got the answer (I have to credit "Ben C" for this). 
The trick (for me was):

unicode-bidi: bidi-override.

Here is the HTML (with a script for testing):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var interval = null;
var count = 10;

function addImage()
{
    var container = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "flowers-100.png");
    container.appendChild(img);

    if (--count == 0) clearInterval(interval);
}

function main()
{
    interval = setInterval("addImage()", 2000);
}

window.onload = main;
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            div
            {
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: scroll;
                direction: rtl;
                border: 2px solid blue;
                width: 600px;
                height: 110px;
                text-align: left;
            }
            div span
            {
                direction: ltr;
                unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
            }
            img
            {
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
        </style>
```

And here is a link to the implementation:

http://www.tidraso.co.uk/misc/imgContainer/

Comment: Ooops, sorry NV, I see you had a similar answer so I credited you. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What about another div inside your scroll div with a float left? Haven't tried it, but I would imagine it works.

Comment: thanks. well, the scoll div is, itself, inside a container div so maybe the same effect could be achieved by floating the scroll div itself? either way, i have been playing with float left and have been unable to get the effect of a left-scrolling series once the right margin has been reached. maybe you could provide an example? thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it to work in IE, but not Firefox:

```
#container
{
    width: 715px;
    height: 228px;
    border: solid 3px purple;
    overflow:auto;
}
#scroll
{
    height: 223px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float:right;
    margin-left: -715px;
    border: solid 2px red;
}
```

Any CSS gurus out there know how to make it work for both?

Comment: By the way, what "isn't" working in FF is that when the page loads, the first image is all the way to the right. In IE, it is at the left of the scroll div and the images overflow left when the right margin is reached.

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work:

```
#container{overflow:hidden;}
#scroll {float:right;min-width:715px;}
```

Not sure how it would work in ie, but you could load code sherpa's solution in a conditional comment for that

Answer (score 0):

Use specific CSS for **IE** like everything else in CSS, for example:

```
#scroll {
    height: 223px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float:right;
    margin-left: -715px;
    border: solid 2px red; min-width:715px;
}
* html #scroll
{
    min-width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#scroll img {float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with your first attempt without `direction:rtl`.
Then in your javascript that adds the image, calculate the position of the new image and set `scrollLeft` on the scroll div:

```
scroll.scrollLeft = theNewImagePosition ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for a project, this is what I did.

```
[ [img1] [img2] [img3] ]
```

The outer DIV wrapping these images is given a width which is equal to the width of all the images (including margins etc).

Then the css property of 'left' is used to shift the row to the left:

```
left: -100px;
overflow: hidden; /* up to you if you need this */
```

The value that it is shifted to the left by, for my example is:

```
width_of_all_images_plus_margins - width_of_display_area
```

Hope that helps, let me know if I haven't explained it enough...